# Converting characters to dates

Tags: r, date

In R, it seems like this should be obvious, but I'm having trouble. I have dates formatted as 1/1/00, 12/31/00, etc., where each part is abbreviated.

When I try to convert it to a date, I get this error:

```
> headlines$Date <- as.Date(headlines$Date)
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I've also tried the below, but get all `NA`s:

```
> headlines$Date <- as.Date(headlines$Date,format="%b/%d/%y")
```

How should I convert this column to dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track by adding the format argument. I'm guessing you realized that the first error ("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format") happened because R doesn't know which of the numbers is the day, month, or the year. Say one of the values was "01/02/03"; there's no way of knowing whether it's 2 January 2003, or 1 February 2003, and so on.

In this case I think you just need to fix what you're passing to the format argument. `%b` is the symbol for abbreviated month in **text** form, not number form (e.g. "Jan" instead of "01"). You need to use `%m` instead for months stored as numbers. Try this:

```
headlines$Date <- as.Date(headlines$Date,format="%m/%d/%y")
```

See [this page](https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html) for more info about date formats in R.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `format = "%b/%d/%y"` with `format = "%m/%d/%y"`.

`%b` means month as in `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar` and so on.

`%m` is the integer equivalent (`1`, `2`, `3` etc).

Further reading: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html